# Add sort order index for manually sorted data.tables

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I have a data.table or a data.frame

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(id = 1:9, name= rep(c('b','a','c'), each = 3))
```

where the column `name` is manually ordered, but always grouped. How can I calculate the `name_order`column to achieve the result below in either Data.table or dplyr?

```
   id  name  name_order
1:  1     b     1
2:  2     b     1
3:  3     b     1
4:  4     a     2
5:  5     a     2
6:  6     a     2
7:  7     c     3
8:  8     c     3
9:  9     c     3
```

Comment: `DT[, names_order := .GRP, by = name]`?

Answer (score -1):

We can use `match` which can applied in both `dplyr` and `data.table`

```
DT[, names_order := match(name, unique(name))]
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
DT %>%
   mutate(names_order = match(name, unique(name)))
```

Comment: The dplyr solution will return wrong output

Comment: @DavidArenburg  Thanks for checking that.  I wrapped it with `sort`

Comment: This is also wrong. This only works because there is an even number of rows in each group. It will fail in any other case. For instance `DT <- data.table(id = 1:10, name= c("b", rep(c('b','a','c'), each = 3)))`. In eitherway, I don't see what your answers adds to the overall SO data base. If you have a solution that isn't present in the dupe target, it's better add it to there.

Comment: @DavidArenburg But, I also showed two other solutions which will work for your example

Comment: @DavidArenburg  The one you duped, doesn't have the 'group_indices', so I am keeping it here

Comment: But `group_indices` gives the wrong result

Comment: @DavidArenburg I don't know about why it is behaving like that (may be bug), anyway, one approach is the `factor/integer` coercsion

Comment: I think it does some ranking first